# How do I stop a comma being added using CONCAT_WS if column is empty

Tags: mysql, concatenation, concat-ws

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', Col1, Col2, Col3 ) AS combined FROM table_name
```

Currently if I have fields Col1 = 'hello', Col2 = 'Bye', Col2 = 'Goodnight'

The above select statement would return hello,Bye,Goodnight which is fine.

What if any of the Cols where blank. A Comma would still be added. like hello,,Goodnight.

Is there a way to say if the Col is empty then ignore it? (This is MySQL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function [**`CONCAT_WS`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) ignores `NULL` values and doesn't generate a separator if either of its arguments is `NULL`.

For empty, i.e. equal to `''`, values you can use [**`NULLIF`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', NULLIF(Col1, ''), NULLIF(Col2, ''), NULLIF(Col3, '') ) AS combined 
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

`CONCAT_WS()` ignores `NULL` values (after the first argument).  Hence, your blank values must be empty strings and not `NULL`.

You can use the `NULLIF()` function:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', NULLIF(Col1, ''), NULLIF(Col2, ''), NULLIF(Col3, '')
                ) AS combined
FROM table_name;
```